# Solve this error flutter and app not lunch in phone now show this error pls solve this error

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Could not create task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-33

pls solve this error
pls tell me

The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Could not create task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-33

Comment: If you are using Android Studio. Go to File--> Project Structure --> SDK --> set the correct SDK Platform version there.